# Chess Themed cryptic clues

Tags: chess, cryptic-clues

In honour of the fortnightly topic challenge, here are some cryptic clues that refer to chess:

> Chewed after leg. It's risky (6)
>
> Ace a piece (6)
>
> Show where Arthur lived (6)

Hint:

> The second clue is about a particular Ace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first:

> gambit. gam, a leg and bit for chewed.

Not sure on the 2nd. (Got it, thanks to Solucutor)

> <strike>Promote is a possibility that fits the clue, but not the number of letters. Pro, an ace, and mote, a piece of dust.</strike> 
>  Bishop, Billy Bishop was a Canadian Ace.

The third:

> Castle, where King Arthur lived, and a popular tv show.

Comment: Promote won't work for the simple reason that it's 7 letters, not 6.

Answer (score 5):

1)

> Gambit (GAM+BIT) a risk

2)

> Knight (as in 'arise sire' is to 'ace' it)

3)

> Castle (an American TV show, Arthur lived in a castle)

Comment: 1st and third are correct but not the second.

Answer (score 3):

1) (Jon Mark Perry and Herb Wolfe)

> **Gambit** (gam = leg, bit = chewed)

2)

> **Bishop** (Billy Bishop was a famous Canadian flying ace)

3) (Jon Mark Perry and Herb Wolfe)

> **Castle** (A TV show and type of structure where King Arthur lived).

Comment: You got it! Now add their answers to yours and I'll accept!

Comment: I'll fill it in, but maybe we should give these guys a chance to fill in #2 and be accepted, since they did most of the work.

Comment: Alright. Sounds good. I'll  wait for whichever of them answers first including your answer. If they haven't in about a day, then I'll accept you.

Comment: I had thought of that for the 2nd clue, but did not know how it fit. Well done!